# Count items and group by a datetime unit

Tags: javascript, sql, datetime, group-by, lovefield

I'm trying to organize a query which should print a `count` of items ordered by a time unit such as a `hour`, a `day` etc.

My limitation is that I'm using [LovefieldDB](https://github.com/google/lovefield/blob/master/docs/spec/04_query.md) javascript library and complex queries are limited.

I have a table of Units where the main field is the date of creation like this:

```
2017/11/29 08:17
2017/11/29 08:47
2017/11/29 09:25
2017/11/29 11:39
```

The result I expect is to count per hour the number of items:

```
08:00 (2)
09:00 (1)
11:00 (1)
```

What I want to avoid is to select all rows and process them in a loop because this software is going to have thousands of rows and I'll have to create similar queries for `day`, `month` and also `year`.

A possible solution I thought is to add 4 more datetime fields where I would save `created_hour`, `created_day`, `created_month`, `created_year` so I can order them easly.

Do you have some tips?

Comment: You can format the datetime column to show the hour and group based on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean. You can format the time to be in hours and group by the formatted time.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, '%H:00'), COUNT(*)
FROM SOURCETABLE
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, '%H:00')
```

Comment: Unfortunately Lovefield doesnt provide a way to write queries manually. And there is no DATE_FORMAT func.